# Barplot in R with year on the x axis

Tags: r

ive created a dataframe in R shown below

```
 df<- data.frame("Year" = c("2011-12", "2012-13", "2013-14", 
     "2014-15","2015-16", "2016-17"),
     "Average" = c(99.03,98.67,96.43,92.74,96.96,93.61) )
```

The error i get is found below:

> Error in barplot.default(df) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

I cant seem to figure out the correct code for a simple  Bar plot with year on the X-axis and the average on the Y.

Would appreciate a bit of help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you using it but this seems to give what you need.

```
barplot(Average~Year, df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use a named vector with `barplot`

```
barplot(setNames(df$Average, df$Year))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option is `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Year, y = Average)) +
            geom_col()
```

-output
[image]

Comment: wow. thanks! how can i make the ylim between 80 and 100 so the height differences betwen each bar is clear?

Comment: @mishal2028 you can use the `ylim` i.e. `barplot(setNames(df$Average, df$Year), ylim = c(0, 100))`